# Astro, Typescript and svelte-check

Tags: typescript, svelte, astrojs

I'm building a frontend project using [Astro](https://astro.build/). For some dynamic components I added [svelte](https://svelte.dev/) as a UI framework.

Now I want to integrate [`svelte-check`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/svelte-check) but the command is failing because of: `Type annotations can only be used in TypeScript files.`

E.g. `export let languageCode: string` doesn't seem to be correct, even though the Astro project compiles fine using `npm run build`.

Any ideas on how to fix this error? Thanks.

Comment: Did you tried renaming your file to use a '.ts' or '.tsx' extension if they are .js files

Comment: Usually svelte components should be name `*.svelte`

Comment: You should provide a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) as there is no such error out of the box with a vanilla astro project and svelte lib added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the issue can be fixed when removing comments in the svelte component.

E.g. having this in the svelte component shows the above error

```
<!--
  Some comment…
-->
```

When removing these lines, the error is gone.

Answer (score -1):

Either you Disable Type Checking for Svelte Files **OR** Use JSDoc for Type Annotations: like below

```
/** @type {string} */ 
export let languageCode;
```